# var becomes NaN after incement by 10 in function

Tags: javascript

```
var post = 10;
function load_more(str) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = document.getElementById("add").innerHTML + xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        var post = post + 10;
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "fetch_more.php?number=" + post , true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}
```

When i load the website i expect the browser to define the value 10 to post and do nothing more until i press a button that calls the load_more() function which increments that value by 10 and passes it to the PHP via Ajax.

The desired behaveiour is to have 10 post on the site and then load 10 more on button press each time the button is pressed.

But PHP just throws an MySQL error and the log shows that the post var is NaN.

Comment: REMOVE `var` from `var post = post + 10;`.

Comment: Bloody hell...it works...thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line

```
var post = post + 10;
```

is the culprit here. Javascript has a behaviour called [**hoisting**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), which essentially means that your variables are always declared at the top of the scope.

So in your code, what happens is the following:

```
var post = 10;
function load_more(str) {
    var post; // `post` is now undefined
    //...other code
    post = post + 10; // undefined + 10 evaluates to NaN
}
```

I hope you can see that since `post` is re-defined at the beginning of the function, `post` is `undefined` when you use it in `post + 10`, which causes `post = post + 10` to evaluate to `NaN` (since `undefined + 10` evaluates to `NaN`).

To solve your problem, just remove `var` from the front:

```
post = post + 10;
```

or:

```
post += 10;
```

Comment: Thanks! A silly mistake from my side. 

It works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1):

You're reinitializing the variable using the keyword `var` and that's the problem.

A simple `post += 10;` would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that **var** indicates declaring a new variable. So you are trying to create a new variable, and set its value to itself + 10. The default value for a new variable is **undefined**, so you were saying "var post = undefined + 10", which is NaN

Answer (score 0):

use `post += 10` or `post = post + 10`

Inside your function remove `var`. It hides variable `post` which is declared outside the function.