# Total becomes NaN after increment 10

Tags: javascript, nan, calculated-columns

I have a [calculation table](https://jsfiddle.net/thebobbyblack/2uyo500c/) and the total becomes NaN after adding 10 rows.
I have even tried the suggestions as stated within this [Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569443/var-becomes-nan-after-incement-by-10-in-function).
I have been testing this for over a day now and cannot fix the error. What am I missing?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    var counter = 2;

    $("#addItem").click(function () {
 
        if(counter>50){
                alert("You have reached the maximum items allowed (50)!");
                return false;
        }   
     
        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('tr'))
             .attr("id", 'itemRow' + counter);
     
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<td class="first"><input placeholder="Charge # ' + counter + '" class="chrg" type="text" name="data[' + counter + '][0]" id="chrg' + counter + '" ></td>' + '<td><input placeholder="Item/Part # ' + counter + '" class="item" type="text" name="data[' + counter + '][1]" id="item' + counter + '" ></td>' + '<td><input placeholder="Description ' + counter + '" class="desc" type="text" name="data[' + counter + '][2]" id="desc' + counter + '" ></td>' + '<td style="text-align:center;"><input placeholder="Qty ' + counter + '" class="qty" type="text" name="data[' + counter + '][3]" id="qty' + counter + '" size="5" style="text-align:center;" /></td>' + '<td style="text-align:right;"><input placeholder="Cost ' + counter + '" class="cost" type="text" name="data[' + counter + '][4]" id="cost' + counter + '" size="10" style="text-align:right;" /></td>' + '<td style="text-align:right;"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input placeholder="Sub-Total ' + counter + '" class="stotal" type="text" name="stotal'+ counter + '" id="stotal'+ counter +'" size="10" style="text-align:right;" readonly /></td>');
     
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
     
        counter++;
     });

    $(document).on('keyup', '.cost', function(st){       
         // grab ID to get row number
        thisID = $(this).attr("id");
        rowNum = thisID.slice(-1); 
        
        //get Amount entered
        qty = $('#qty'+rowNum).val();
        //get QTY
        cost = $('#cost'+rowNum).val();        
       $('#stotal'+rowNum).val((qty*cost).toFixed(2));
        
      currentCount = counter-1;
      var tot = Math.round(0);
        $('.stotal').each(function() {
            tot += parseFloat($(this).val());            
        });
          
    $('#preTotal').val((tot).toFixed(2));
    $('#grand_total').val((tot).toFixed(2));
    });
 
//calculate preTotal
    $(document).on('focusin', '#shipping', function(pt){
 var selection = document.getElementById("addShip");
  if (selection.checked){
  $("#shipping").change(function(preTotal,shipping) { // input on change
    var preTotal = document.getElementById('preTotal').value;
      var shipping = document.getElementById('shipping').value || 0;
    var pTotal = parseFloat(shipping) + parseFloat(preTotal);    
    
    document.getElementById('preTotal').value = (pTotal.toFixed(2));
  });
  } else {
    var preTotal = document.getElementById('preTotal').value;
      var shipping = document.getElementById('shipping').value || 0;
    var sTotal = parseFloat(preTotal);    
    
    document.getElementById('preTotal').value = (sTotal.toFixed(2));
  }
 });

//calculate taxes and total
    $(document).on('focusin', '#taxTotal', function(tt){
 var selection = document.getElementById("addShip");
  //get field results  
  var preTotal = document.getElementById('preTotal').value || 0;
  var shipping = document.getElementById('shipping').value || 0;
  var taxTotal = document.getElementById('taxTotal').value || 0;
  var taxRate = document.getElementById('taxRate').value || 0;
  var gTotal = document.getElementById('grand_total').value || 0;

  $("#taxTotal").change(function() { // input on change
    var tTotal = document.getElementById('taxTotal').value / document.getElementById('preTotal').value * 100;
    document.getElementById('taxRate').value = (tTotal.toFixed(2));
  });

    });
 
//calculate total + taxes
    $(document).on('focusout', '#taxTotal', function(gt){
  var shipping = document.getElementById('shipping').value || 0;
  var tTotal = document.getElementById('taxTotal').value || 0;
  var gTotal = document.getElementById('grand_total').value;
  var fTotal = parseFloat(shipping) + parseFloat(tTotal) + parseFloat(gTotal);
  document.getElementById('grand_total').value = (fTotal.toFixed(2));
    });

});

}

function focusField() {
    $('#addItem').click(function(){
    $('.chrg').focus();
 });
```

```css
th     {padding: 2px 2px;}
td     {padding: 2px 2px;}
input    {padding: 0px 2px;}
#addItemBtn  {}
input.filler  {border-color:#fff;border-style:solid;}
.input-group-addon {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #555;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #eee;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0  0 1px grey;
 border-right: 1px #eee solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="TextBoxesGroup" style="width:100%;">
   <tr>
     <th style="text-align:left;">Charge #</th>
        <th style="text-align:left;">Item/Part #</th>
        <th style="text-align:left;">Description</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Qty</th>
        <th style="text-align:right;">Cost</th>
        <th style="text-align:right;">Sub-total</th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="itemRow1">
        <td><input placeholder="Charge # 1" class="chrg" type="text" id="chrg1" autofocus /></td>
        <td><input placeholder="Item/Part # 1" class="item" type="text" id="item1" style="margin-bottom:0 !important" /></td>
        <td><input placeholder="Description 1" class="desc" type="text" id="desc1" /></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;"><input placeholder="Qty 1" class="qty" type="text" id="qty1" size="5" style="text-align:center;" /></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;"><input placeholder="Cost 1" class="cost" type="text" id="cost1" size="10" style="text-align:right;" /></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input placeholder="Sub-Total 1" class="stotal" type="text" id="stotal1" size="10" style="text-align:right;" readonly /></td>
    </tr> 
</table>
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr id="rowFiller">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addItem" value="Add Item" size="10" style="float:right;" onclick="focusField()" /></td>
     </tr> 
     <!--<tr id="addItemBtn">
      <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="addItem" value="Add Item" style="float:right;" /></td>
     </tr>-->
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
        <label style="padding-right:5px;">remove shipping from taxable total
        <input type="checkbox" id="addShip" class="addShip" name="addShip" checked ></label>
        </td>    
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
        <label style="font-weight:bold;padding-right:5px;display:inline-block;">Shipping</label>
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input placeholder="$00.00" name="shipping" id="shipping" size="10" style="float:right;text-align:right;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
        <label style="font-weight:bold;padding-right:5px;display:inline-block;">Pre-Total</label>
        <input name="preTotal" id="preTotal" size="10" style="float:right;text-align:right;" readonly /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
        <div style="text-align:right;display:inline;border-right:1px #ccc solid;margin-right:5px;">
        <label style="font-weight:bold;padding-right:5px;display:inline-block;">Tax</label>
        <input placeholder="00" class="taxRate" name="taxRate" id="taxRate" size="1" style="text-align:center;" />
        <label style="font-weight:bold;display:inline-block;">%</label>
        </div>
        <label style="font-weight:bold;padding-right:5px;display:inline-block;">Total Tax</label>
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input placeholder="$00.00" name="taxTotal" id="taxTotal" size="10" style="float:right;text-align:right;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;"><label style="font-weight:bold;padding-right:5px;display:inline-block;">Grand Total</label>
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input placeholder="$00.00" name="grand_total" id="grand_total" size="10" style="float:right;text-align:right;" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Update:
I have resolved the issue as shown in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thebobbyblack/2uyo500c/) provided.

Comment: Please add a tag of the language you are programming/scripting in to the question.

Comment: You really need to reduce this problem to less code. I seriously doubt a number is becoming NaN after adding 10 to it. More likely a scenario is the number you thought was real is actually NaN, then you're adding 10 to that.

Comment: Whoops, realized I misunderstood the problem. The suggestion still stands though. There's a lot of code here, and I doubt 90% of it is even relevant.

Comment: What variable *specifically* is becoming NaN?

Comment: The Grand Total returns NaN after 10 rows.

Comment: @BobbyEtheredge Have you stepped through it with a debugger?

Comment: I am not returning any errors on anything.

Comment: the function focusField is not closed properly

Comment: @BobbyEtheredge But did you use s debugger? After more than 10 minutes of not being able to figure it out, the first thing you should have done is fire up a debugger and step through your problem. If your total us becoming NaN, one of the things you're adding to it must be NaN.

Comment: I removed function focusField and get the same result.

Comment: `parseFloat` returns NaN on a bad parse. That's almost definitely your problem.

Comment: What would you suggest to keep the calculations displayed in the dollar amount?  - used FF debug

Comment: @BobbyEtheredge You should ensure prior to parsing that the number is actually parsable. Have your program crash on a bad parse, and examine what went wrong.

Comment: If this is jQuery, please tag as such. Also, please strip down your case to about 20-30 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Add below condition to your code before actually parsing the values to float.

```
if(preTotal === ""){
    preTotal = 0; // assign number value you like
}
```

and

```
if(gTotal === ""){
    gTotal = 0; // here also.
}
```

Because, for the first time, these values come as empty strings.

Also, I noticed the "focusin" event being handled here. It fires the handler everytime user goes to put something inside the test box provided.

Comment: I added if(preTotal) under var selection and if(gTotal) in function(gt) and produced the same results.

Comment: I had also removed the event handlers for focusin event. Try doing that..

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Comment: I have found that NaN is coming from function(st).  The val of qty*cost on the 10th is the culprit.

Comment: Glad to know you figured it out :)